# Multiple Projects on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I work for a company that has many projects running, a lot of which are in maintenance.

I get moved between projects as need be, for example when we are waiting on new requirements for one project, I move to a project which has currently incomplete requirements.

Is there a way to have multiple date ranges for a single project? Or an alternative to reflect the above mentioned scenario?

Listing the same project multiple times as a new projects would look very messy and confusing.

Comment: "Is there a way to have multiple date ranges for a single project?" is the only part of the question that's on topic here. Focus on that, otherwise it would be closed as being out of scope

Comment: Updated the question